# How to use sed command regexp group to pass data from group to section $()

Tags: sed, logs, date

I want to change date in mail.log to timestamp format using sed command.
There is a problem how to pass \1 from group to date command inside $() ?

```
sed -E "s/(^.{15})/$(date -d "\1" "+%s")/" /var/log/mail.log
```

Comment: use perl, with the Date::Parse and Date::Format modules.  You're just going to give yourself a nasty headache dealing with the quotes and command substitution with sh + sed.  e.g. `perl -MDate::Parse -pe 's/^.{15}/str2time($&)/e' /var/log/mail.log`

Comment: If using GNU `sed`, add `e` after final `/` for "eval". Totally unsafe and not tested though.

Comment: both Date::Parse and Date::Format are library modules, not included with the standard perl distribution.   If you're running debian or ubuntu, you can install them with `apt install libtimedate-perl`. They're probably packaged for other distros too. Otherwise you can install them with `cpan`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a lesson in quoting and expansion :-)

```
"s/(^.{15})/$(date -d "\1" "+%s")/"
```

So, the argument is a concatenation of:

- `'s/(^.{15})/$(date -d '`, which is passed as-is
- `\1`, which is interpreted by the shell
- " " (a single space) which is passed as-is
- `+%s` which is interpreted by the shell
- `)/` which is passed as-is.

What you wanted is:

```
s/(^.{15})/$(date -d "\1" "+%s")/
```

with the date part expanded by the shell.

There are two ways to achieve that. Creative quoting:

```
"s/(^.{15})/$(date -d '\1' '+%s')/"
```

or picket-fencing:

```
"s/(^.{15})/$(date -d \"\1\" \"+%s\")/"
```

But that still won't work, because the `date` runs at the time that the command line is expanded and not for every line in your file. So `date` sees only `\1` and it will complain about an invalid date. Just once: at the start, not at every line.

So, `perl` or `bash` is a better choice than `sed`.

Comment: +1, for all of it, but especially for the paragraph with "because the date runs at the time that the command line is expanded". it's good to explain why something won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the use of `GNU sed` as we are invoking the `/e` modifier for the `s///` command of sed. And since you didn't share any input data, iam assuming it may be more than 15 characters.

```
sed -E 's/^(.{15})(.*)/echo "$(date -d "\1" "+%s")\2"/e' /var/log/mail.log
```